# iOS app that calculates multiple lines

Tags: engines, software

Does anyone know of a chess engine for iOS that calculates and gives multiples lines when analyzing positions? I currently use Stockfish, but it only gives one variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My strong SmallChess iOS app. Multi-lines is supported:

[image]

You can also try each variation on a variation board:

[image]

Comment: Where is it available?
Could not locate it on AppStore

Comment: @pabitrasaha Google "SmallChess iOS".

Comment: @StudentT I've found it under "SmallChess". When I searched for "SmallChess iOS" it didn't find anything. Will it be available for iPad? Or do you have another app that does similar for iPad?

Comment: @BU982T I am working for iPad update. This is a hobby project so I am doing as best as I can.

Comment: @StudentT I'd love to see it on iPad. Thanks!